# Finding the solutions of $\sin\left( x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \sin\left( 3x + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all the solutions for $x$ in the following equality.
>   $$
>  \sin\left( x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)
>  = \sin\left( 3x + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)
> $$

I tried using the following formulas for both sides but I got stuck.
$$ \sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a) $$
$$ \sin(a-b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\cos(a) $$
Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You could do $\sin\left( x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)
 - \sin\left( 3x + \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = 0 $ and then use $\sin C - \sin D$ formula

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sin\alpha=\sin\beta$ if and only if
$$
\alpha=\beta+2k\pi
$$
or
$$
\alpha=\pi-\beta+2k\pi
$$
(for integer $k$).

Answer (score 0):

$\sin\left(x-{π \over 4}\right)=\sin\left(3x+{π \over 4}\right)$

$\arcsin\left(\sin\left(x-{π \over 4}\right)\right)=\arcsin\left(\sin\left(3x+{π \over 4}\right)\right)$

$x - \frac {\pi}{4} = 3x + \frac\pi4$

But this only account for solutions in the $arcsin$ domain.  So the solutions are also $x+2\pi n$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You convert all $sin$ into $cos$

$$sin\ {(x-\frac{\pi}{4})} \ = sin \ {(x - \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4})} \ = - cos{(x + \frac{\pi}{4})}$$

$$sin \ {(3x + \frac{\pi}{4})} \ = sin \ {(3x + \frac{3\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2})} = -cos \ {3(x + \frac{\pi}{4})}$$